# Setup Project for WCF - how to add "Select Installation Address"

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, installation

We have an MSI created by a programmer that left.  It has a "Installation Address" dialog box.  When I create a new default setup project, I have an "Installation Folder" dialog box.  The "Install Address" dialog at install time says "Select Installation Address" and allows the person doing the install to select the application pool.

I'm trying to figure out how to get this magic dialog box into a new setup project.  I realize it could have been a custom dialog box, but when we click the "Installation Address", the properties window doesn't show all the customizable options that a user interface custom dialog has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I added the setup project, I selected "Setup Project" instead of "Web Setup Project".  Selecting the proper project makes the difference.